# Alternative to redis with pub sub persisted messages and key value store?

Tags: python, redis

I am looking for an alternative to redis that has pub sub persisted messages. So I can get the last message published through the service. And a key value store. There are so many services out there I'm not sure which has these functions. I'm using it with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pub/sub with persistence: [Nats Streaming](https://nats.io/documentation/streaming/nats-streaming-intro/), [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/), [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and many others. Also note, that Redis will also have this functionality (called Redis Streams) in version 5 soon.

And still Redis for key/value. There is memcached, etcd, and million other key-value stores, but what do you need that Redis doesn't have?

Comment: Pub/sub persistence. I found a way around it though.

Comment: @Brian Hello, how could you persist the messages? Thanks in advance.